# How to render messages in real time - FLASK PYTHON

Tags: python, flask

i have a follow code
--- app.py

```
from test import printing
@app.route('/start_all')
def start_all():
    printing()
    return 'ok'
```

--- test/printing.py

```
for c in range(10):
    print(c)
    render(c)
```

---

i want render c in realtime, how i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow the below steps:

1. Install Flask-SocketIO:

```
pip install flask-socketio
```

2. **app.py:**

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'randomSecretKey@123'
socket = SocketIO(app, cors_allowed_origins="*")


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


@socket.on('start_all')
def start_all():
    from function_start_all import start_all
    start_all()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    socket.run(app)
```

3. **index.html:**

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.3.6/socket.io.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:5000')

    socket.on('connect', function() {
        console.log('Successfully connected to server!');
        socket.emit('start_all')
    })

    socket.on('start_all', function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    })
</script>
```

4. **fuction_start_all.py:**

```py
from flask_socketio import emit


def start_all():
    for c in range(10):
        emit('start_all', c)
```

By now, your project's root directory will be looking like below:

```
Project
|
|-> templates
|   |
|   |-> index.html
|
|-> app.py
|
|-> fuction_start_all.py
```

After successfully running the Flask App, upon opening `http://localhost:5000/`, if you view the browser's console, you would see that the range from 0-9 has been logged.

Comment: oh, tank you!

but... if i want that...
the above code be in another directory? ex:
https://pastebin.com/kse6QpHe